# Interesting Secure Copy Behavior

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, file-copy

I'm not entirely sure where to ask this question, so if this is not the right place just let me know and I'll move it.

Today I was trying to using recursive scp to copy a directory between two Linux servers and made a typo when referring to the destination server. Instead of transferring the directory to the other machine, it began to transfer the file back into itself. It took a while for me to notice what it was doing since the directory was so large, but then I started seeing the same files popping up again and again on the transfer status until I killed it. It confused me that this was allowed and I have a few questions.

I guess my main question I would like to ask you all, though, is if there is ever an instance when a user would need to make a secure copy to himself on the same machine or is it an unnecessary side effect of scp that was just shrugged off?

Edit - Sorry guys, here's the actual command

`scp -r /path/to/dir SameUser@sameserver:/path/to/dir`

Comment: Which switches did you use with scp? Do you have the full command line?

Comment: If you supply local source and destinations, `scp` just calls `cp`.

Comment: @jsbillings Is that still the case with the the syntax I added?

Comment: I carried out a simple test and the behaviour with `cp` is different, as it doesn't allow to copy a directory over itself:
`$ cp -r /tmp/test /tmp/test` (line break) `cp: cannot copy a directory, ‘/tmp/test’, into itself, /tmp/test/test’`. With the `scp` line you supplied an infinite recursion takes place.

Comment: @Claudio And there's absolutely no reason to scp something to yourself?

Comment: `scp -r /tmp/test /tmp/test`, without any hostname references does seem to call `cp` indeed, as the error message is exactly the same as `cp -r /tmp/test /tmp/test`.

Comment: If your goal is just making the copy, I can see no reason to go over the network for it :)

Comment: @degausser: no, if both the source and destination are local, it uses `cp`, but as far as `scp` knows, hostname:path is a remote path, which is why you saw what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For copying files on the same machine you wouldn't need `scp` at all. Anyway, if you specify a directory or file as destination instead of a hostname and a path it will copy it for you locally, which seems to be what happened. If you supply the command line you used we can point you what happened exactly.

**EDIT:**
With the supplied command line, what it does is to go over the network interface, connect to the SSHD server on your local machine and then make the copy. There is no good reason for that since you can copy it locally with `cp`.

Comment: edited  to show command

Comment: Thank you sir. I need to go learn a little more about ssh protocols I think :)

Comment: You're welcome! Think of `scp` as a secure `ftp` (there's an exact equivalent in the form of `sftp`, which is also part of **openssh**). What it does is to copy a file to or from a remote server through an encrypted channel. You wouldn't ever need the extra overhead of encryption and network connection if you are doing things locally, where you have complete control over the system.

Answer (score 1):

It's a special case that's rarely useful. But to detect it would be difficult, harmful and useless.

Difficult, because how do you know that it's the same user on the same machine? There are plenty of rare edge cases where even `ssh $USER@localhost` does not contact the same account, and the `scp` program isn't always in a position to tell. For example:

- `localhost` does not point to the local machine, due to an unconventional but legal DNS or `ssh_config` alias.
- `ssh` is invoked from inside a chroot, but the ssh server is running outside the chroot, or in a different chroot.
- The ssh port on the local machine bounces connections to another machine.
- `scp` is invoked from a session with reduced privileges; on the remote site of `scp $USER@localhost`, the user's default privileges hold.

Harmful because it would complicate the behavior of `scp` a lot. Instead of “copy files, using SSH as the transport”, it would become “copy files, using SSH as the transport, except if the source and destination are detected to be the same user on the same machine”. Yuck. Then, if someone writes a script that happens to use scp and takes machine and user names as parameters, the script would have to include a special case: if the source and destination happen to be the same account on the same machine, then call `cp` instea of `scp`. The script writer would have to match `scp`'s logic exactly.

Useless because it would only catch one possible typo among many. Why bother? You might have typed the name of a different server, or mistyped the path, or the username, etc.